# Why Kotlin compiler gives an error in a valid IF statement?

Tags: android, kotlin

It started to appear for me a very weird compiler error in *Kotlin*

So I have reduced my  code to the simplest form. The code doesn't make sense, but it is much easier to try to understand where the error comes from.

I've posted my code in [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org). So I don't  depend on any local configuration of my computer and the error can be reproducible instantly anywhere for anyone.

My complete code

```
data class Pilha(
    var funs: ArrayList<Int> 
          = arrayListOf<Int>()  
)

var AP: Array<Pilha> = Array<Pilha>(5) { Pilha() }
fun main() {
    var ele: String=""
    var cl: String = ""
    when (ele) {
        "soul" -> {
            with(AP[0]) {
                when {
                    (cl == "%") -> {
                       if (funs[0]==1)   // <= error in this line
                            cl = "a"
                    }

                    cl == "xU" -> {
           // If I comment this line, the error disappears
                        funs.add(2) 
                    }
                    else -> { cl="b" } // else of inner when
                } // when
            } // with

        } // "soul"
    else->{ cl="c"}  // else of outer when
    } // when
    println("ok")
}   // main
```

The error message

```
if must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression
```

This error gives in this line

```
if (funs[0]==1)
```

If I comment this line, the error disappears

```
funs.add(2)
```

it is a big mistery because it's obvious that is a valid `if` flow control statement. I'm not using `if` as an expression.

Obviously putting a dead `else` (`else {}`) on this `if` also solve the error, but don't explain it.

Kotlin Playground:

[image: Kotlin Playground]

**Update**: As  [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) has pointed out to me, it's a question of type return conflict, linked to `with` statement. As I am a classic *Pascal*  programmer, I was using `with`, how Pascal users did it.

For this purpose, it is best, like Pawel said, using `object.apply {}`. So  one can, as in the case of `with`,  use the properties and methods of the object directly without the accessor dot inside brackets ({}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `with(AP[0]) { ... }` function with lambda signature of `T.() -> R`. It REQUIRES a return value from within the lambda, and last statement inside it is `when` block so it is used as an expression to determine return value.

Error is caused because in case of `cl == %` and `funs[0]!=1` it's not possible to determine value to return.

Fix it by replacing your `with` with a scoping function that does not need return value, for example `AP[0].apply { ... }` with signature of `T.() -> Unit`.

**Edit**: why commenting out `funs.add(2)` "fixes" the error?

It's because that call returns `Boolean` value which changes signature of entire `when` block:

```
// this when block can be used as an expression because it returns value of type Any
when {
    (cl == "%") -> if (funs[0]==1)  cl = "a"  // if true returns Unit, else undefined
    cl == "xU" ->  { funs.add(2) }    // returns Boolean
    else ->  cl="b"        // does not return value (Unit)
}
```

Now when you comment out `funs.add(2)` or change second case to `{funs.add(2) ; Unit }` this makes return type of entire `when` block a `Unit`, which means it's no longer used as an expression and returning value is not required.

```
// this when block cannot be used as an expression because it always returns Unit (void)
when {
    (cl == "%") -> if (funs[0]==1)  cl = "a"  // does not return value (Unit)
    cl == "xU" ->  { funs.add(2); Unit }    // ignore add return value by returning Unit
    else ->  cl="b"        // does not return value (Unit)
}
```

Comment: The ambiguity about returnv value is not solved by commenting the line 
`funs.add(2)`, however when you do it, the error vanishes and the Kotlin Playground prints `ok`. Why?

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum it is because `funs.add(2)` returns `Boolean` value. I edited my answer.

Comment: I've understood the logic, but I don't agree with `Kotlin` designers, it's a very technical syntax error, above of simple mortals guys like me.

Comment: `Apply` is a nice solution for this imbroglio, avoiding artificial workarounds.

Comment: Awesome explanation, thank you! I ran into this with a 'let' block, and in that case I found that 'also' was the easiest replacement.